# Best way to bulk delete records in Datasheet model?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a Datasheet model with ~ 4000 records. Occasionally, I'll need to delete all the data and reload from a Google sheet. I'm able to delete a page of data, one row at a time with this code:

```
var set = widget.datasource.items;
set.forEach(function f(i){i._delete();});
widget.datasource.load();
```

The problem is that this is slow and problematic with pages of more than around 20 records. Is there a way to bulk delete records? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the app.deleteRecrods() method in a server script:

```
function clearData() {
  var query = app.models.Student.newQuery();  
  var records = query.run();
  app.deleteRecords(records);
}
```

Call it from a client script:

```
function clearData() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
    console.log('Clear all Student data.');
  }).clearData();
```

}